# Setting global body font size does not work

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

- Stack: Nuxt.js + Vuetify.js
- Issue: Setting global body font size is not working
- Attempt:
  In **~/assets/style/app.styl**, I set the body font size to 40px:

  ```
  // Import Vuetify styling                                                                                                                        
  $body-font-size = 40px;                                                                                                                          
  @require '~vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl'
  ```
- Output: It does not take effect:

[image: font]

- Note: same thing happens with `@body-font-weight`
- Question: Why this happens and how to overcome it?
- Link to reproduce: [here](https://github.com/begueradj/bug-vuetify-nuxt-font-size)

Comment: How you are using this variable?

Comment: I do not use it. Vuetify use it because setting it followed by the `@require` instruction is supposed to override the Vuetify default value related to this key.

Comment: Try by setting `important` like this `$body-font-size = 40px !important;`

Comment: At this level, IMHO we do not need to specify that, however I tried it but it does not work. Thank you for the suggestions though

Comment: _“Link to reproduce:”_ - I think you meant link to go and download this and then go set up a proper environment to test this in … yeah, nope, sorry. Provide a live example somewhere, instead of expecting everyone here to go through that process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are using vuetify loader plugin. So your changed variables should go into variables file, not into app.styl

So your `assets/style/variables.styl` should look like this:

```
$font-size-root = 40px;                                                                                                                          
@require '~vuetify/src/stylus/settings/_variables.styl'
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it does not take effect. Note that when I define `@body-font-family` in `assets/style/app.styl` it takes effect (but anything else does not). Thank you

Comment: @Begueradj what is antyhing else? ANd i have checked, there no body-font-size in vuetify, its called $font-size-root thats why its not working